# Injecting a connection string with StructureMap not working

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I'm still very new to Structure Map so I can't understand why this is not working. I'm injecting a "connection string" to a repository and I keep getting the following error from Structure Map:

**StructureMap Exception Code:  205
Missing requested Instance property "purchaseOrdersFilePath" for InstanceKey "a04b4f71-4171-4e9f-b98d-170fc9ee005f"**

*On a side note, the connection string is in quotes because I'm playing with linq to xml as well so the "connection string" is actually a path to a file. I'm adding this just in case it might have something to do with the issue.*

My code is as follows:

```
public class PurchaseOrderRepository : IPurchaseOrderRepository
{
    private readonly string PurchaseOrdersFilePath;

    public PurchaseOrderRepository(string purchaseOrdersFilePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(purchaseOrdersFilePath)) throw new ArgumentNullException("purchaseOrdersFilePath");

        PurchaseOrdersFilePath = purchaseOrdersFilePath;
    }
 }
```

On my Global.asax file I have the following configuration statement:

```
private void RegisterControllerFactory()
{
    var ioc = new Container();

    var controllerFactory = new IocControllerFactory(ioc);
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);

    ioc.Configure(r => r.Scan(x =>
    {
        x.AssemblyContainingType<HomeController>();
        x.AddAllTypesOf<IController>();
        x.Include(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t));
    }));

    ioc.Configure(r => r
        .ForConcreteType<PurchaseOrderRepository>()
        .Configure.Ctor<string>().Is(@"C:\Users\sromero\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DIDemo\SupportFiles\POS.xml"));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that I was configuring the same component twice (which I didn't reflect on the sample code in the question), so what I was doing is this:

```
ioc.Configure(r => r
                .For<IPurchaseOrderRepository>()
                .Use<PurchaseOrderRepository>());

    ioc.Configure(r => r
            .ForConcreteType<PurchaseOrderRepository>()
            .Configure.Ctor<string>().Is(@"C:\Users\sromero\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DIDemo\SupportFiles\POS.xml"));
```

When what I should have been doing was this:

```
ioc.Configure(r => r
                .For<IPurchaseOrderRepository>()
                .Use<PurchaseOrderRepository>()
                .Ctor<string>().Is(@"C:\Users\sromero\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DIDemo\SupportFiles\POS.xml"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
.Ctor<string>("purchaseOrdersFilePath").Is(@"C:\Users\sromero\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DIDemo\SupportFiles\POS.xml"));
```

Comment: Thanks but, it didn't work. I still got the exact same error.